# What is the difference between request.args[] and request.args.get() in Python Flask?

Tags: python, flask, query-string

Just genuinely curious, say I have a url ending in the following `/home?id=2`. Which is more efficient to use to obtain the id value from the url, `request.args['id']` or `request.args.get('id')`?

Comment: `request.args` is a dictionary. `request.args['id']` this is fetching value from key(`id`) and `request.args.get('id')`  call `get` function to fetch 'id' key value.

Comment: ...they're both a *"dictionary approach"*. The only difference is that [`.get(...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) will return `None` if the key isn't found instead of throwing a `KeyError`. I would expect almost no difference in speed at all, but you could `timeit` if you really wanted - this is unlikely to be a bottleneck in your program.